# Мне нужно доработать функцию!

Tags: javascript, node.js, функции

У меня есть код:

```
  String.prototype.chunk = function(length) {
    return this.trim().replace(/\s*\n\s*/g,"\n").match(new RegExp('[^]{1,' + +length + '}', 'g'));
  }
```

Иногда случается так что он делит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужно вот так(Есть если в конце есть \n то строка не разделялась,а переносила текст на следующий индекс массива ):

```
emojis:[GuildEmojiManager]}
```

Возможно ли так сделать?

Comment: 1) как "так" и "так"? 2) Не мучайте String.prototype

Comment: Есть если в конце есть \n то строка не разделялась,а переносила текст на следующий индекс массива

Comment: 0) она и так на "\n" не реагирует; в конце чего? что значит "не разделялась,а переносила"?
1) вы json chunk-ами делаете? а зачем?

Comment: Смотрите есть например у меня текст:
```
emojis:[GuildEmojiManager]}
```
А он может записатся вот так
`
1 сообщение
emoji
2 сообщение
s:[GuildEmojiManager]}
`
А мне нужно проверять если в конце текста есть \n 
И оно не влазит в текущий месседжс,то переносить его на следующий

Comment: 1) Если что-то не влазит в текущий месседжс, то оно уже в любом случае пойдет в следующий (в том числе `\n`). 2) Что такое "конец текста"? конец всего текста, который есть (`}\n`)? 3) возможно вы хотите, чтобы `\n` могло быть только в начале чанка, но чанки при этом были ограничены по длине?

Comment: Я хочу чтобы чанки не разделяли вот так как на скриншоте,а разделяли по принципу
если часть сообщения : \n Текст \n  и он  не влазит,то сейчас оно перенесёт вот так \n Текс и 2 сообщение  т \n,а мне нужно что бы оно проверяло на целостность строки то есть чтобы отправило \n Текст \n на 2 сообщение т-к оно не влезло в 1-вое

Comment: А если строка длинная, тогда разбивать?

Comment: Я не о том,если  ЧАСТЬ сообщения на примере \n Текст \n, и так сложилось что он не полностью влазит в чанк,то  тогда перенести его на следующий чанк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делите на строки `const lines =` ... `split("\n")`, добавляя обратно "\n" всем кроме одной, и деля большие line вашей старой функцией (в `flatMap`).

`const result = []`

Делаете в обычном цикле для каждой line:

- или `+` к последней группе в `result`
- или `push` новой группы (если превышен размер)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое

Comment: Всегда рад. Принимайте ответ галочкой.

Comment: Я поставил,но не пишет что мнение людей с репутацией  ниже 15 учитываются но не показываются

Comment: Там **галочка** должна быть рядом; а то вопрос неотвеченным считается

Comment: А нашёл  и поставил

Comment: this.split(`\n`).flatMap(x => x.trim().replace(/\s*\n\s*/g,"\n").match(new RegExp('[^]{1,' + +length + '}', 'g')));

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1172715/Функция-работает-не-совсем-как-нужно

Там образовалась 1 ошибочка,может я вас не так понял.

Comment: добавил вариант https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1172879/395779 ; если не надо объединять в чанк короткие строки -- еще проще вышло.