# Функция работает не совсем как нужно!

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вот код:

```
  String.prototype.chunk = function(length) { 
    const lines = this.split(`\n`).flatMap(line => line.trim().replace(/\s*\n\s*/g,"\n").match(new RegExp('[^]{1,' + +length + '}', 'g')));
    const result = []
    for(line of lines){
      if(result.length <= 0){
        result.push(line)
      }
      else if (result[result.length -1].length < length){
        result + line
      }
      else{
        result.push(line)
      }
    }
    return result;

}
```

Он выводит лишь 1 строчку
например у меня есть текст:
`Я Енд,или же Kristalkill\nМне 14 лет`.chunk(10) то он выведет [`Я Енд,или же`],а должен вывести  `['Я Енд,или же','Kristalkil,'l\n','Мне 14 лет']`,в чём проблема и как пофиксить?

UPD1:
Вот,что смог сделать(не без помощи друзей),но пока результат не очень утешителен

```
String.prototype.chunk = function(length) {
    let result = []
    let lines = this.trim().match(new RegExp('[^]{1,' + +length+ '}', 'g')).filter(x => x);
      for (let line of lines){
       result.push(line)
      }
    return result
    }
```

Comment: Простите за прошлый вопрос :)

Comment: понятно, а что должен вывести?

Comment: Должен вывести  ['Я Енд,или же','Kristalkil,'l\n','Мне 14 лет']

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME,мне нужно чтобы он делил сначала по length,а если там есть \nТекст\n и он не влазит в этот чанк ,то нужно чтобы он перенёс \nТекст\n  на следующий чанк

Comment: `'Я Енд,или же'` — вижу 12 символов) Если не считать пробелы, 10. Ошиблись примером или он правда не должен учитывать пробелы?

Comment: Не должен учитывать,т-к дискорд тоже не учитывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(За основу взят вариант @OPTIMUS PRIME)

Вроде и одной регуляркой выходит:

```js
String.prototype.chunk = function(len){ 
    return this.match(new RegExp("(?: *[^\\n]){0," + (len-1) + "}\\n|(?: *.){1," + len + "}", "g"))
}

console.log("Я Енд,или же Kristalkill\nМне 14 лет".chunk(10))
```

И со своим тримом, т. к. `.trim()` убирает `\n`:

```js
String.prototype.chunk = function(len){ 
    return this.match(new RegExp("(?: *[^\\n]){0," + (len-1) + "}\\n|(?: *.){1," + len + "}", "g"))
        .map(c=>c.replace(/^ +| +$/g, ''))
}

console.log("Я Енд,или же Kristalkill\nМне 14 лет".chunk(10))
```

Короткие строки в чанк не склеиваются.

Answer (score 3):

Была бы задача - просто разбить на "чанки" в размере до `min(length, "до первого \n")`, подошла бы такая регулярка: `/[^\n]{0,9}\n|[^]{1,10}/g` — т.е. всё что угодно, кроме переноса строки, от 0 до 9 штук и до первого переноса строки. ИЛИ `|` всё что угодно от 1 до 10 шт:

```js
let str = "Я Енд,или же Kristalkill\n\nМне 14 лет";

String.prototype.chunk = function(len) {
  let reg = new RegExp("[^\\n]{0," + (len-1) + "}\\n|[^]{1," + len + "}", "g");
  
  let lines = this.trim().match(reg);
  
  return lines
};

console.log( str.chunk(10) );
```

Но необходимость "не учитывать пробелы" делает невозможным решить это одной регуляркой. Решил бы таким циклом:

```js
String.prototype.chunk = function(len) {
  let result = [], curr_chunk = "", counter = 0;

  for (let char of this) {
    switch (char) {
      case " ": // Пробел? Добавляет в текущую строку, ничего больше не делая
        curr_chunk += " ";
        break;

      case "\n": // Перенос строки? Считает как отдельный chunk + сбрасывает счетчики
        push_n_reset(curr_chunk + "\n");
        break;

      default: // Любой другой символ
        curr_chunk += char; // +символ к текущей строке, увеличивает счетчик
        if (++counter == len) push_n_reset(curr_chunk); // Дошел до len? push!
    }
  }
  
  if (curr_chunk) result.push(curr_chunk); // Остался кусок строки после перебора.
  
  return result;

  /***/
  function push_n_reset(chunk) {
    result.push(chunk);
    curr_chunk = "";
    counter = 0;
  }
};

let str = "Я Енд,или же Kristalkill\nМне 14 лет";
console.log(str.chunk(10));
```

Если должен вырезать пробелы вначале и конце каждого chunk - можно вызывать функцию так: `push_n_reset( curr_chunk.trim() );`